# Unable to deploy jar file at unix environement

Tags: java, spring, maven, unix

I have a standalone application with spring Boot and maven used for building application.I am trying to move this jar file to different unix environment and trying to deploy it.While trying to execute I am getting below error

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-01-10 10:16:27.345 ERROR 13211 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:735)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:716)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:703)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:304)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)

Comment: Rerun with debug enabled?

Comment: Can you elaborate how to do that.Because in properties file we keep debug=false only and thats how it run in all environments and in my local as well.I am able to run the same jar in some other unix environment but not this unix environment.Is it like jars have some artifact or like.I am totally new to this.Please help!!

Comment: No idea, but that is what the error message suggested.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen error message shared in the question

Answer (score 0):

Below is the command to start a springboot application.

> java -jar path/to/executable.jar

Please make sure if you can execute the above command to start the spring boot application in windows.

If it runs fine in windows then o please check if you have required access to run jar in unix machine.

Comment: I was unable to run jar through this command.I tried in some other unix environment and it did got execute.the same jar is executing in one environemnt but not other.I have access to that environment.what could be the issue?